# Positioning reCAPTCHA widget with CSS

Tags: html, css, forms, recaptcha

I'm trying to align the reCAPTCHA widget with my input fields, but styling .g-recaptcha doesn't seem to achieve much. Does anyone know of any selectors I can use?

Form HTML:

```
<div class="contact-form">
  <form role="form" method="post" action="contact-form.php">
    <label for="name"><span>Name</span><input type="text" class="input-field" name="name" required data-errormessage-value-missing="Please enter your name." /></label>
    <label for="email"><span>Email</span><input type="email" class="input-field" name="email" required data-errormessage-value-missing="Please enter your email address." /></label>
    <label for="message"><span>Message</span><textarea name="message" class="textarea-field" required data-errormessage-value-missing="Please enter your message."></textarea></label>
    <span>&nbsp;</span>
    <div id="recaptcha">
      <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LcBawsTAAAAAKBPfGs1jApXNRLvR2MIPng0Fxol" style="margin: 0;"></div>
    </div>
    <label><span>&nbsp;</span><input type="submit" value="" class="submit-button" /></label>
  </form>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.contact-form {
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    max-width: 600px;
    font-family: 'LinotypeUniversW01-Thin_723604', Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
}

.contact-form label {
    display: block;
    margin: 0px 0px 15px 0px;
}

.contact-form label > span {
    width: 100px;
    text-align: right;
    float: left;
    padding-top: 8px;
    padding-right: 20px;
}

.contact-form input, .contact-form textarea {
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: none;
}

.contact-form input.input-field {
    width: 70%;
    height: 20px;
    font-size: 18px;
}

.contact-form .textarea-field {
    width: 70%;
    height: 250px;
    font-size: 18px;
}

textarea {
    resize: none;
}

textarea:focus, input:focus {
    outline: 0;
}

#recaptcha {
    width: 304px;
    margin: 0;
}

.g-recaptcha {
    text-align: left;
}

input.submit-button {
    background-image: url("../img/submit-button.jpg");
    width: 225px;
    height: 60px;
    border: none;
}
```

Any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: use can use !important; keyword with your style to over-ride the inline styling

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just modify your existing CSS with this:

```
.contact-form label, #recaptcha {
    display: block;
    margin: 0px 0px 15px 0px;
}
.contact-form label > span, #recaptcha::before {
    width: 100px;
    text-align: right;
    float: left;
    padding-top: 8px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    content:""; //Make sure you add this as well
}
.contact-form .textarea-field, .g-recaptcha {
    width: 70%;
    height: 250px;
    font-size: 18px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Pseudo elements are used here so that you don't have to change your markup. `:before` works as a span inside the label thus providing uniformity in your html structure and hence solving the alignment issue

Comment: Had to add `<label>` around `.g-recaptcha`'s `<span>`, which I somehow left out, and adjust the CSS slightly, but this did it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

To align `reCAPTCHA` with rest of the other `form-fields` you have to change your `DOM` structure something like this:

`HTML`:

```
<label for="captcha">
   <span>&nbsp;</span>
      <div id="recaptcha">
             ...
```

then also change/write the `CSS`:

```
#recaptcha {
   margin: 0px;
   width: 304px;
   position: relative;
   float: left;
}

#recaptcha iframe {
   position: absolute;
   left: 0px;
   top: 0px;
}
```

This will do the trick for you.